# Is Inner Join the correct join to use here?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to update a column with the same name in two different tables for a user. The column is `userCanMessage`

**userMain**

```
userId | userCanMessage
1      | 0
```

**userSettings**

```
userId | userCanMessage | userCanAdd
1      | 0              | 0
```

The whole thing is structured this way for a good reason.

If I wanted to update `userCanMessage` in both tables for `userId = 1` what would be the safest method to do it in one query?

Currently the one is:

```
update userMain inner join userSettings on userMain.userId = userSettings.userId 
   set userMain.userCanMessage = 1,
       userSettings.userCanMessage = 1
  where userMain.userId = 1;
```

Here, `userMain` is the main Table for users, and `userSettings` is the table that holds setting. The update need to affect both tables, with `userMain` first.

Comment: any specific reason NOT to use two separate queries?

Comment: `The whole thing is structured this way for a good reason.` - perhaps you should share the reason, duplicating fields across tables is rarely a good idea. Also, which join to use depends on what you want to happen if the userId doesn't exist in userSettings. Do you still want the userId in userMain to update if it doesn't exit in userSettings?

Comment: @Daniel When a user is setup (verified) a record gets created in `userMain` as well as `userSettings`. So there always will be a record in both tables. No, the `userId` in `userMain` should not update if it's not found in `userSettings`. Although something like that is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Makes thing easier. For this example I've only used one field. There are more.

Comment: @jmenezes inner join in this case is no harm since you are updating based on userId, to make things faster make sure they are same datatype in both tables with same length say int(11) and have them indexed.

Comment: @jmenezes - You still haven't answered _why_ you've got duplicated fields, especially as your comment on the existing answer indicates you have **more** instances of this.  This is exactly why denormalization is usually a bad idea - you're now running into the overhead of dealing with it.  Among other things - what happens when (not if) the columns get out-of-sync; which version do you trust?  You could rig a trigger that would update all "children" tables, but that would still be masking the larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `JOIN`? Make it 2 simple queries.

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE userMain SET userCanMessage WHERE userId=?";
$sql2 = "UPDATE userSettings SET userCanMessage WHERE userId=?";

$stmt1 = $db_usag->prepare($sql1);
$stmt2 = $db_usag->prepare($sql2);

$stmt1->bind_param('d', $param);
$stmt2->bind_param('d', $param);

$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();

$stmt1->close();
$stmt2->close();
```